# How to disable ion-split-pane from a single page in ionic app?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I'm creating a web app and i want it to be in a consistent split pane mode so i declared it in app.component.html as

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
  <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
...
```

and for every other page my header looks like this

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="danger">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title class="ion-text-center">Details</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div class="content">
    <ion-toolbar>
...
```

and it works perfectly.

Now, I've decided to add a landing page to my app which can have basic info and a sign in/up button. But when i create a page I'm not able to disable the split pane.

So far Ive tried removing the header section from the landing page's html and adding

```
constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {this.menuCtrl.enable(false); }
```

to the landing page's .ts file but nothing works and its always showing the split pane which was the point but i just need one page without it.

Any ideas or tips??

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to your split pane tag named #ionSplitPane:

Html:

```
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content" #ionSplitPane>
```

Ts:

```
//import .... 
import { IonSplitPane } from '@ionic/angular';
//import .....
 @ViewChild('ionSplitPane') ionSplitPane!: IonSplitPane;
constructor(){}
disableIonSplitPange(){
    this.ionSplitPane.disabled = true;
}
```